# Forms and nested resources in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-resources

I have 4 models Users, Clients, invoices and Items

Currently a user can click on a client and see all the invoices from that client. However when he chooses to create a new invoice, the new invoice is already assigned to a client. I also want the ability for the users to create a new invoice and to choose a client from a list or make a new one.

Routes & Models

```
devise_for :users
resources :invoices, only: [:new]
resources :clients do
resources :invoices, shallow: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :invoices
has_many :clients

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :invoices
has_many :items, through: :invoices

class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :invoice
belongs_to :client
```

I added the line `resources :invoices, only: [:new]` to `routes.rb` file and `<%= link_to 'New Invoice', new_invoice_path(@invoice) %>` to `aplication.html.erb`

However I have set up my `new` action to work only when creating an `invoice` on the `route` `/clients/:client_id/invoices/new`

invoicesController

```
def new
 @client = Client.find(params[:client_id])
 @invoice = @client.invoices.new
end
```

And my form

```
<%= simple_form_for [@client, @invoice] do |f| %>
```

If I change my controllers new action to

```
def new
 @invoice = Invoice.new
end
```

I get `undefined method invoices_path for #` I know this is coming from the way I set up my `form`

How can I make both routes work off of the one controller action? Should I have 2 forms?

Comment: you didn't show the code where invoices path is...run `rake routes` and make sure that's the proper helper for invoices...since you nested the route it most likely isn't.

Comment: The line `resources :invoices, only: [:new]` outside the nested resource block creates the route new_invoice GET   /invoices/new(.:format)

Comment: but the error was undefined method `invoices_path`! which is why adding create fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you also need to enable :create in routes (where form_for will link to via the post method) and have a controller action

```
def create
```

handling the input of the form. otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Thanks, I added `resources :invoices, only: [:new, :create]` to my routes 
and changed my form to `<%= simple_form_for (@invoice) do |f| %>` and it works as expected